# Child added to Window decor View does not fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I was playing with fitsSystemWindows. I added a FrameLayout (P) to Window DecorView. I then added another FrameLayout (C) as child to P. I set C's fitsSystemWindows to true. But C's paddingTop returns 0. So does P's, as well as DecorView's paddingTop.

Yet the background drawable I had set for C, is cut off in status bar as well as in Navigation bar area. If the PaddingTop was zero what had caused this cut off?

Comment: so what `"Inset"` are you talking about? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink want to understand the behaviour. In the docs, it is given that the padding of the View is adjusted. But I'm always getting View's paddingTop as Zero. 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows

Comment: see `View#fitSystemWindowsInt(Rect insets)` method code then

Comment: @pskink I read through the docs. I now understand, fitsSystemWindows is meant to be used in cases like where system bar is hidden/set translucent. In my case where I added a FrameLayout to decor View, I'm not making system bars hidden or translucent, but the added FrameLayout occupies the whole screen covering system bars as well. That is why I was trying to use fitsSystemWindows

Comment: Have a look at https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec